# How to get the same ls with colors working on both OSX and Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, osx, ls, colors, alias

When I want color in Ubuntu I do

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

but on OSX this gives an error `ls: illegal option -- -` and I need to do

```
alias ls ='ls -G'
```

How can I create an alias with the same code and have it work on both systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
ls --color=al > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls -F --color=al' || alias ls='ls -GF'
```

Basically it sees if ls color=al works.  If no error (`2>&1`) use it, else (error) use the other format.

The `test_condition && ... || ...` is bash shorthand for `if test_condition then ... else ...`

Comment: I suppose your keyboard likes to eat the  `&` :)
It was not `test_condition &&... || ...` ?

Comment: good catch Hastur.  Fixed that.